# How to install Ubuntu Touch to a Jolla Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, porting-ubuntu-touch

I'd like to install Ubuntu Touch on my Jolla Phone device. Is it possible? Any guides on how to do that? Has anyone tried theirself?

Edit: I see Jolla Phone isn't on the list of currently supported devices, but since Jolla is having financial problems (and maybe even going down), I think there might be demand for a port in the near futue. At least I don't want to be stuck with the current version of Sailfish OS forever. Porting should be possible, since Jolla Phone is Android HW and the OS is running on top of Android drivers.

Comment: Even if it is possible it would be wise that you try the [Emulator](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator) first because Ubuntu Touch is still not exactly ready for everyday use.

Comment: Well, at least it is not dying any time soon. Sailfish isn't that polished either, and I've been living with it for some time now without too many problems.